# if some .c file include other .c file, what can i do to build a shared_library? There is no hdrs in the rules of cc_binary

Tags: c, linux, dll, header-files, bazel

My project was compiled with cmake before, i want to use **bazel** to rebuild my project, but some error occurred.
There is a .c file containing the following code

```c
#define XXX
#include "ABC.c"
#undef XXX
```

there is the question.

If I want to compile a dynamic library,
Where should I put this file in cc_binary? There is no **hdrs** in cc_binary, but I can't put this file in **srcs**, because the ABC.c cannot be compiled .

```
cc_binary(
    name=""
    srcs=[],
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to include C files

Comment: I'm not the only person responsible for this project, and I can't change it, so...lol

Comment: You may have to change it. Don't overlook the possibility. What you have now is certainly bad practice and needs to be fixed some time.

Comment: sry, but do I have any other options? @user207421

Answer (score 2):

Use the `textual_hdrs` attribute of `cc_library`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = 'mylib.so',
    linkshared = True,
    deps = [':lib'],
)

cc_library(
   name = 'lib',
   srcs = ["source.c"],
   textual_hdrs = ["include.c"],
   alwayslink = True,
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but if A deps B, the mothed does not work.  Do I have to merge A and B together

Comment: What are the definitions of A, B, and "mothed"?

Comment: cc_binary( name = "mylibA.so" )   cc_library( name=A, deps=[:B] )  cc_library( name=B,....) 。 it will look like mylibA.so will be missing the content of B

Comment: B presumably needs `alwayslink = True`.